# Set DateTime in App.Config

Tags: vb.net, app-config

I have a service that needs to receive configuration from APP config to make it easier to update when you need to change the search criterias - for example if error occurs.
so, saying that I would like to know how to set a Datetime value in app.config

I want something like:

```
<add key="MyDate" value="DateTime.Now" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to default this setting to `DateTime.Now`, or to allow a specific value to be specified, then you probably want some code like this:

```
Dim magicDate = If(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("OverrideMagicDate")),
         Date.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("OverrideMagicDate")),
         Date.Now)
```

And now in `app.settings` you leave the `OverrideMagicDate` setting value empty to get `DateTime.Now` or you supply a specific date.

```
<add key="OverrideMagicDate" value="" /><!-- DateTime.Now -->
```

or:

```
<add key="OverrideMagicDate" value="2012-01-13" /><!-- 13th Jan 2012 -->
```

You might need to switch [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want more control over what format of dates you accept.

Answer (score 0):

Example in C#:

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MyDate" value="2014-01-01" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In the form... with DateTimePicket and Button generates for example:

```
private void bChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    AppSettingsSection app = config.AppSettings;
    app.Settings["MyDate"].Value = this.dtMyDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
}
```

Comment: It's a example with DateTime input, you can replace this.dtMyDate.Value to DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();